# PHP and MySQL $_POST Security and md5() hash function

Tags: php, mysql, security, md5

I am creating a information system that will handle financial information, contacts, etc. I am developing the site from complete scratch using object oriented programming (classes, functions, etc). A majority of the data will be from a MySQL database. Users will be able to get and submit data to the database.

I am already using the hash function to encrypt data such as passwords, serial keys. I am also using preg_replace() function for all other data going to the database.

What other security measures do I need to take to insure that submitting and getting data from the database does not compromise security?

Comment: Please let me know the name of the site so I can avoid it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you concerned about security of data _inside_ the database or during transmission?

Comment: hash is not encryption, preg_replace what? why?

Answer (score 3):

md5 is a *[cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)*. once hashed, it cannot be "un-hashed" back to the original value (one-way) as opposed to [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) which is two-way (encrypt-decrypt).

for security of your data, consider these scenarios and ways of prevention instead of just encryption:

- [cross-site request forgeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (CRSF) - prevent using form tokens
- [SSL connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) (the "httpS://") to prevent data interception in transport
- [hash salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to further protect (but not totally) hashed passwords from dictionary attacks. weak and common passwords are the targets in this case.
- hashing is not absolute. there is a limit to how many combinations of letters and numbers in a hash. at some point extremely different strings may have the same hash value. this is known as a [collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29)
- hashes are prone to brute-force/dictionary attacks. although hashes are one way, one can create a string-hash dictionary, match the hash and figure out the string behind it.
- [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) which can include (but not limited to) cookie stealing, click jacking, etc.
- [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - ways to trick your SQL when forms are unsanitized
- expendable [session ids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID) to track user sessions - which should expire in a given amount of time, hence an auto log-out mechanism.
- identify your user! user ip address, browser detection, etc to profile your user. any odd data (like sudden change in IP, location etc.) should be considered within a certain threshold. (facebook has this feature. i once accessed my facebook using a proxy - auto lockdown)

Comment: I like this advice and I will review this the first change I get.

Comment: it's not a complete list though. it's just the common ones.

Comment: MD5 **is not encryption**. You have no guarantee that the hash you have was generated from the value you store, otherwise it would be a fantastic compression algorithm.

Comment: “hash salting to further encrypt hashed passwords and avoid collisions” — First, salting doesn’t encrypt anything. And second, it doesn’t avoid collisions; you will inevitable have collision as you map an infinite amount of input values onto an infinite amount of hash values.

Comment: @Gumbo i'll change that. thanks for pointing out these things. cryptography (and math) is not really my forte

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace()` will not do much in terms of security. You should familiarize yourself with some basic security/crypto before doing this work. Also, consider the use of a standard cryptographic library for encrypting/decrypting data instead of arbitrarily using hash or regex functions.

Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Answer (score 1):

First: good for you for giving attention to security issues.  It's a big subject and one that many people overlook until it's too late.  So, kudos to you for seeking more understanding about best practices.  :-)

[OWASP](http://owasp.org) is a good resource for understanding web security issues.

Another good resource is the SANS report [The Top Cyber Security Risks](http://www.sans.org/top-cyber-security-risks/).

Specifically, [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) are the top two security risks for most websites.  You should read about how to design your code to minimize these risks.

I have also designed a presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) that goes deeper into the nature of this issue and methods of defense.

Read the blog [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html) by StackOverflow founder Jeff Atwood.

I also cover SQL injection and password hashing in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have good liability insurance if you are using md5 to secure financial information.  Read about md5, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5, paying close attention to the line

> The security of the MD5 hash function is severely compromised.

Comment: I like the last user's suggestion of SHA1. What do you believe is the best encryption algorithm to use?

Comment: neither md5 or sha1 are "encryption algorithms" you should understand that before doing anything security related

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, because:

- md5 is considered broken,
- preg_replace() will not give you much.

Consider using already developed, tested and secure frameworks (candidates include Zend Framework, Symphony, Kohana, Yii) for your system. You have a long way before you will achieve security at least nearly as good as standard framework's. Also consider using prepared statements instead of preg_replace() and salted sha1 instead of simple md5, if you still want to reinvent the wheel.

Furthermore:

- secure your app against such acronyms as XSS, CSRF,
- require SSL at all times (for every request, even for images / styles / scripts),
- read security newsletters (you will need them if you want to build secure system for financial activities).

Comment: Why is md5 considered broken. The only purpose I use it for is to store passwords. I think its a great encryption tool.

Comment: I read the first answer and understood your reasoning behind your option of the md5

Comment: Where can I get more information about SHA1's algorithm or function?

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu: It is broken, because a method shorter than brute force attack has been discovered to be able to reverse it. And **it is definitely not an encryption tool**, it is a hashing algorithm. Hashing algorithm is meant to be onew-way-only as much as possible. MD5 fails in meeting that requirement. Even simple message scripts stopped using MD5 in new code, especially when there is no salt, and **especially for password storing**. Is it clear? Why downvote?

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu: On Wikipedia for example (sorry, I am writing from my phone and finding out more is really as simple as searching on Wikipedia/Google). In PHP function hashing values using SHA-1 is called... `sha1()`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, md5 is broken. Also, a SHA1 hash is very fast to compute which actually makes it **worse** as a hashing algo. Instead look at bcrypt. Assuming you're using PHP, the http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ is very a nice password to use that handles hashing and salting for you transparently.

Using preg_replace() for escaping data to the database is a **very bad idea**. Almost all databases include their own sanitization functions, PHP/MySQL is no exception with mysql_real_escape_string().

Some more points (please note none of these are set in stone):

**Sanitize all input**
Assume that everything the user sends to your server is designed to cause harm. This includes form submissions, but also URL routes, cookie values, server vars, EVERYTHING. Using a framework will often provide some insulation from this, automatically escaping a lot of data for you.

**Escape all output**
Assume that everything you display on your site is designed to cause harm. **XSS** and **CSRF** are amongst the most common techniques for attacking websites. Escape all text that you output to the browser. Look into using nonces to mitigate attacks.

**Use TLS/SSL**
If you want to protect your users data enroute, get yourself a signed SSL certificate and set it up. This allows visitors to go to https://yoursite.com securely (or at least more securely if they're the kind of person who does internet banking on coffee shop wifi).

**Use a framework**
Everyone begins by writing their own framework because they know how to do it right, or don't need the extra complexity or whatever reason they come up with. Unless you're writing a super-specific-niche-application for which PHP probably isn't the right answer anyway, **use a framework**. I prefer http://kohanaframework.org/, but there's a whole range out there from http://codeigniter.com/ through to http://framework.zend.com/. Frameworks handle session encryption, database escaping, input sanitization and more for you, and because they're used by many people the chance of a bug is much less than code that only one person has worked on.

**Secure your infrastructure**
This one tends to fly by most people, but make sure you take some time to look at the server(s) you're running on. Are you on a shared account? You don't want to be storing financial information on them then (in some countries it's even illegal too). Apply security patches for your OS/software, make sure you haven't left an old upload script lying around, check your file permissions, use SSH with keys and turn off password logins. Attackers are always looking for the easiest way in.

At the end of the day, the only way to stay secure is to sleep with one eye open, totally paranoid. Watch your logs, install Nagios and set-up some alerts, hire a professional to do a security audit. There's no such thing as 100% secure, but knowing that is half the battle.

Answer (score 0):

I am an experienced PHP developer and I want suggest to you to take a look to this project [OWASP_Development_Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Projects/OWASP_Development_Guide). Every web developer should be use it as a bible. It has been very useful for me and I hope it will be the same for you.

Here a brief description of the document:

> The Development Guide provides practical guidance and includes J2EE, ASP.NET, and PHP code samples. The Development Guide covers an extensive array of application-level security issues, from SQL injection through modern concerns such as phishing, credit card handling, session fixation, cross-site request forgeries, compliance, and privacy issues.